# Tips to solve equation with square root

Tags: roots, problem-solving

I have a quite complex (at least for me) equation that is driving me a bit insane this days... I tried to solve it for two days but no way, so I'm asking for **tips** (not necessarily solve it) on how to solve it.

So, I start from this expressions (where $n$ it's a variable, and the rest are known values):

$
\frac{-qn -p +\sqrt{q^2n^2+bn+a}}{c}
$

$
\frac{-qn -p -\sqrt{q^2n^2+bn+a}}{c}
$

This expressions come from an algorithm that, given a number $m$ will return these with fixed values for $p, q, a, b, c$, and also two additional parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Giving real values they give a concrete result for each value of $n$. As an example:

```
for m = 4723891, algotihm will return:

p = 44100
q = 1000
a = 39410000
b = 87840000
c = -200

Then, for "n = 127" (found using brute force, incrementing n from 1 by 1)

first result: 29 (x)
second result: 1682 (y)
```

Then, I can apply

$
(10(x-1))+k_1 = 281 (k_1 = 1);(10(y-1))+k_2 = 16811 (k_2 = 1)
$

and finally

$
281*16811=4723891 = m
$

So, the full equation will be:

$
(10(x-1))+k_1*(10(y-1))+k_2=m
$

So, when applying the general solution (the expressions given by my algorithm), I have the following equation:

$
(10(\frac{-qn -p +\sqrt{q^2n^2+bn+a}}{c}-1))+k_1*(10(\frac{-qn -p -\sqrt{q^2n^2+bn+a}}{c}-1))+k_2=m
$

So, here I'm trying to calculate $n$ (in this example, will be $127$) for the general form of the equation (I mean, for any set of fixed values that the algorithm will return for any possible input $m$), but I'm not succeding.
First thing I did, for simplicity, was rename the square root as

$
\sqrt{q^2n^2+bn+a} = R
$

so it will be a bit easier to solve, but I'm still stuck. After some calculations I have

$
\frac{(-10qn-10p-10c+k_1c+10R)(-10qn-10p-10c+k_2c-10R)}{c^2}=m;
$
$
(-10qn-10p-10c+k_1c+10R)(-10qn-10p-10c+k_2c-10R)=mc^2;
$

After developing the product, I'm still having some $R$ (that mean, the square root), after a rearrange, it looks like

$
(10q^2n^2+20qpn+20qcn-qk_2cn-qk_1cn-k_1cR+k_2cR+10R=((\frac{mc^2}{10})+(10p^2-20pc-pk_2+10c-k_2c-k_1pc-k_1k_2c)
$

And I don't know how to get rid of $R$ (I mean, don't having $n$ inside of the square root)
Did I forgot something on the way that can make this easier?

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear. An equation has an equals sign in it. What you are calling an equation at the top of your post isn't an equation, since it has no equals sign in it. Please edit the body of your post for mathematical correctness.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done. I called it now expressions... sorry I'm not very deep on the math language.

Comment: "So, I start from this expressions" Why?  Surely you started from something else *before* you got those expressions.  I suspect you got those as a step toward solving something which I suspect might be easy to just solve from the beginning.

Comment: That's a lot of variables to determine from one equation. If they're unconstrained real or complex numbers, there will be many solutions; what makes some $n=127$ solution the "better" or "right" one?

Comment: OK. Now, in addition to $p,q,a,b,c,n,x,y$, you conjure up $k_1,k_2,m$ from nowhere. And then you want to calculate $n$. Not at all clear what's given, what's meant to be found, and what equations are to be satisfied.

Comment: @fleablood, sure, it comes from a 200-page paper that I wrote last year...

Comment: @aschepler I added some info about it. They are fixed values depending on each value of "m" (there's an algorithm that returns the values for a given value of m, so on an specific case, they will be fixed and known values)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added some info about it. Sorry my head was ahead of my hands... hope now it understand better

Comment: @DavidSoléGonzález "*how to get rid of R*" $\;-\;$ Isolate $R$ on one side and square the equation. You'll end up with a quartic in $n$, though.

Comment: @dxiv so then I will end with $(k_1cR+k_2cR+10R)^2 = ([anyting else])^2$ ritght?

Comment: @DavidSoléGonzález Right, what you have is something like $\alpha R + \beta=\gamma$ and you get $\alpha^2R^2=(\gamma-\beta)^2$.

Comment: @dxiv ok, then just need to join all constants multiplying $R$ like $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)R$ then will be easier... Thanks, I think I get it!